# Regular expression that allows spaces in a string, but not only blank spaces

Tags: regex, whitespace

I need to write a regular expression for form validation that allows spaces within a string, but doesn't allow only white space.

For example - `'Chicago Heights, IL'` would be valid, but if a user just hit the space bar any number of times and hit enter the form would not validate. Preceding the validation, I've tried running an `if (foo != null)` then run the regex, but hitting the space bar still registers characters, so that wasn't working. Here is what I'm using right now which allows the spaces:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9_:,.' ']{1,100}$
```

Comment: Which language? Java/C#?

Answer (score 48):

It's very simple: `.*\S.*`

This requires one non-space character, at any place. The regular expression syntax is for Perl 5 compatible regular expressions, if you have another language, the syntax may differ a bit.

Comment: Just noticed that. Have deleted, and offer my apologies.

Comment: This doesn't address the 100 character maximum, though. Your `.*` is also broader than his character class.

Comment: I didn't read the 100 as a requirement, only as what the original poster tried so far. The limit can be expressed as a regular expression, but since regular expressions cannot count characters, this would be a nuisance to write. It's much simpler to completely ignore regular expressions in this case and to write `s = s.trim(); if (s.length() >= 1 && s.length() <= 100) { ... }`

Comment: Won't this trim function also delete white space between words?

Comment: That of course depends on the programming language you use. The ones I often use (Java, Python, Perl) only trim at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: I had to use `.*\w.*`instead because `.*\S.*` didn't catch strings with a single irritating no-brake-space-character in it (U+00A0).

Answer (score 10):

The following will answer your question as written, but see my additional note afterward:

```
^(?!\s*$)[-a-zA-Z0-9_:,.' ']{1,100}$
```

**Explanation:** The `(?!\s*$)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It means: "The following characters cannot match the subpattern `\s*$`." When you take the subpattern into account, it means: "The following characters can neither be an empty string, nor a string of whitespace all the way to the end. Therefore, there must be at least one non-whitespace character after this point in the string." Once you have that rule out of the way, you're free to allow spaces in your character class.

**Extra note:** I don't think your `' '` is doing what you intend. It looks like you were trying to represent a space character, but regex interprets `'` as a literal apostrophe. Inside a character class, `' '` would mean "match any character that is either `'`, a space character, or `'`" (notice that the second `'` character is redundant). I suspect what you want is more like this:

```
^(?!\s*$)[-a-zA-Z0-9_:,.\s]{1,100}$
```

Comment: This seems like what I was looking for, but for some reason the blank whitespace is still passing the regex in my script. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @user699242 - Hmm. It seems to work correctly here: http://rubular.com/r/V8nlkU7E5R and with some letters thrown in: http://rubular.com/r/8qjj4Z2PWs. What language of regex are you using?

Comment: This is the most correct answer, I feel. The negative lookup does exactly what was required.

Answer (score 6):

You could use simple:

```
^(?=.*\S).+$
```

if your regex engine supports positive lookaheads. This expression requires at least one non-space character.

See it on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/8OqMMq1DzR).

Answer (score 0):

If we wanted to apply validations only with allowed character set then I tried with `USERNAME_REGEX = /^(?:\s*[.\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[.\-_]*\s*)$/;`

- A string can contain any number of spaces at the beginning or ending or in between but will contain at least one alphanumeric character.
- Optional `., _ , -` characters are also allowed but string must have one alphanumeric character.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[^\s]+(\s.*)?$
```

It means one or more characters that are not space, then, optionally, a space followed by anything.

Comment: This expression does not allow spaces.

Comment: That would allow only non-spaces.

Comment: This doesn't allow spaces at the beginning. The requirement was only that the string cannot be **all** spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `\s*` to avoid one or more blank spaces in the regular expression between two words.

For example, `"Mozilla/   4.75"` and `"Mozilla/4.75"` both can be matched by the following regular expression:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*/\s*[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}
```

Adding `\s*` matches on zero, one or more blank spaces between two words.