# Regex which allows alphabets and spaces combination but not only spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, web, pattern-matching

I want to know the regular expression which allows the combination of alphabets and space but it shouldn't allow only the spaces.

I have searched and read all the articles and found the expression /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/ which allows only spaces also along with the combination of alphabets and space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is to just `ok = pat.test(str.trim());`

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600349/3832970).

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, it helps but I want to validate it using pattern attribute of HTML5.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't checked out the HTML5 pattern attribute myself from MDN but if it expects regex pattern only, then this question isn't duplicate. If this isn't duplicate, please unmark it as such. Thank you!

Comment: @Calvin: It is a dupe because the answer is *"add the `(?!\s+$)` after `^`"* - I even pointed to that answer in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your expression require one alphabet and then the additional alphabets and spaces are optional:

```
/^[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\s]*[A-Za-z]$/
```

Also that `\s` means any whitespace characters (tabs, newlines, carriage returns etc), not just space.

(edited: my earlier answer was flawed. This new one ensures input is either just one alphabet, or has to start and end with alphabet with spaces allowed only in between.

Comment: Something like  /^[\s]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z\s]*$/

Comment: Hi Calvin, thanks. Your suggestion made me to form the regular expression myself and it is `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s]*`