# Regex should not only contain spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `/^[A-Za-z.,' -]+$/`

But unfortunately, `/^[A-Za-z.,' -]+$/.test('     ')` returns true.

How can I ensure that there is at least 1 non space character.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599934/regular-expression-that-allows-spaces-in-a-string-but-not-only-blank-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regex:

```
/^(?=\s*\S)[A-Za-z.,' -]+$/
```

`(?=\s*\S)` is a **positive lookahead** to assert we have a non-space character ahead after matching 0 or more spaces.