# Regex in js may contain spaces at the start of a character after or at the end but must not have only spaces

Tags: regex

i have a requirement that needs an expression that might have space at the beginning of the character at the end and in the middle but it should not contain only spaces.For example:1)(space)  a b c->valid    2)a b c (space) valid but space space space is not valid. I have this expression

```
^([A-Za-z0-9,\u002D][A-Za-z0-9,\u002D]*[\\s]?)+$
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600203/3832970 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/5600349/3832970

Comment: Simple stuff `^(?![ ]+$)[ A-Za-z0-9,-]+$`